# No android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED meta-data

Tags: android, nfc

I implement a app to read nfc tag. But it can't read tag with "android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED". Here are things I did:
(1) add intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml within activity

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

(2) add file "nfc_tech_filter.xml" in /res/xml/ like this:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcBarcode</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

But my app can't get any TECH_DISCOVERED intent. I find there is an error in logcat:

```
W/RegisteredComponentCache(1404): Unable to load component info ResolveInfo{41fe1748 com.example.nfcapp/.MainActivity m=0x108000}
W/RegisteredComponentCache(1404): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: No android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED meta-data
```

So I unzip my nfcapp.apk, and check the "nfc_tech_filter.xml" is still there in "/res/xml/". I don't why it cannot parse the meta-data or is something wrong in configuration?
Is anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the permission and the feature in your Manifest?
Is your minimum SDK set to 10?
The meta-data tag must be OUTSIDE your intent-filter

Comment: You are right. The meta-data should be outside the intent-filter. And this issue is gone.